# Leaflet controls unchecked when initialized

Tags: leaflet, gpx

I'm creating a leaflet map with multiple (gpx) tracks loaded via an ajax call.

The tracks are organised in categories so the user can switch which tracks he wishes to see.

The problem I have is that the checkboxes within the control are unchecked and the user has to first check the checkbox and then un check to hide the track, which is bad ux.

After doing many different variations nothing seems to work, right now the code looks like this

```
const mapLayer = new L.map("map");
const points = L.layerGroup();
const trackLayer = L.layerGroup();
const markers = [];
var inited = false;

var markerIcon = [],
    markerIconDetails = [],
    categories = {},
    popintsLayer;

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.osm.org">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(mapLayer);

var categoriesControl = L.control.layers();
var markerControl = L.control.layers();

var apiUrl = '/api/';
var locateOptions = {
    strings: {
        title: "where am I?"
    },
    position: 'bottomright'
};

L.control.locate(locateOptions).addTo(mapLayer);

function initMarkers( trackId ) {

    jQuery.getJSON(apiUrl + 'trackmarkers/' + trackId, function(json, textStatus) {
        $.each(json, function(index, marker) {
            addMarker(marker);
        });
    });
}


function initGPX( map, mapLayer ) {

    for (var i = map.tracks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var track = map.tracks[i];

        var lineOptions = {
            weight: 10,
        }

        if (typeof track.map_file_option.color != 'undefined') {lineOptions.color = track.map_file_option.color}
        if (typeof track.map_file_option.weight != 'undefined') {lineOptions.weight = track.map_file_option.weight}
        if (typeof track.map_file_option.dasharray != 'undefined') {lineOptions.dashArray = track.map_file_option.dasharray}

        var tempPopup = L.popup();

        new L.GPX(track.path, {
            async: true,
            polyline_options: lineOptions,                

        }).on('loaded', function(e) {

            var gpx = e.target;
            mapLayer.fitBounds(gpx.getBounds());
            map.categories.forEach( (category) => {
                if( categories[category.name] ) categories[category.name].addLayer(gpx);
            });

            tempPopup.setContent(popupData(gpx,map.id, track));

        }).on('click',function(e){fitMap(e.target)}).on('mouseover', function(e){highlightLayer(e.target)}).addTo(mapLayer).bindPopup(tempPopup);
    }
}

function highlightLayer(target){
    target.bringToFront();
    // target.setStyle({weight:20});
}

function fitMap( layer ) {
    highlightLayer(layer);
    mapLayer.flyToBounds(layer.getBounds());
}

function popupData( gpx,mapId, track ) {
    var title = track.title ? track.title : gpx.get_name();
    var description = track.description ? `<p class="track-description">${track.description}</p>` : '';
    return `<h4 class="popup-title">${title}</h4>${description}`;
}

function loadMaps( mapsJson ) {
    $.each(mapsJson, function(index, singleMap) {
        initGPX( singleMap, mapLayer );
    });
}

function createMapGroups( json ){
    json.forEach( ( category ) => {
        categories = {
            ...categories,
            [category.name]:  L.layerGroup()
        };
    });

    $.getJSON(apiUrl + 'tracks', function(json, textStatus) {
        loadMaps(json);

        document.querySelector('.core_loader').classList.remove('-show');
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector('.core_loader').classList.remove('-front');
        }, 300);
        L.control.layers(null,categories).addTo(mapLayer);
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON(apiUrl + 'categories',function(json, textStatus){
        createMapGroups(json);
    });

    mapLayer.on('popupopen', function(e) {
        $('.track-description').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.getJSON( apiUrl + 'trackdescription/'+ $(this).data('map-id'), function(json, textStatus){
                $('#modal').addClass('visible');
                $('#modal .modal__title').html(json.name);
                $('#modal-content').html(json.description);
            });
        });
    });


    $.when(  loadMaps() ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

        document.querySelector('.core_loader').classList.remove('-show');
          setTimeout(function(){
              document.querySelector('.core_loader').classList.remove('-front');
        }, 300);

    });
});
```

Just to be frank, the code has gone through many iterations and right now I'm stuck and placing it as it is so far is to create a separate `var categoriesControl = L.control.layers();` then adding it to the map 
 `categoriesControl.addTo(mapLayer,'tracks');` after reading through documentation and posts I got nowhere.

**edit**

a temporary solution that i came up with, is to iterate all checkboxes and then trigger the click event on them.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    if(inited) return;
    $('.leaflet-control-layers-selector').each(function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
    inited = true;
});
```

This is the categories view after load:
[image]

Comment: In your question you are stating that "seems to work right now". What is the question then?

Comment: Is says "nothing seems to work", I've edited the question a little.

Comment: A picture or two would help in understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've added an image with commentary. The idea is that the checkboxes should be checked, so the user can hide the tracks he does not wish to see. The hiding works on but first the boxes have to be checked and then unchecked.

Comment: I created simple example for myself and it works as you expect it to work. Which version of Leaflet are you using?

Comment: That's interesting, i use 1.6.0+Detached.